# Grub error whenever installing anything

Tags: apt, grub2, software-installation, uefi

Hi guys I am having grub errors every time try to install anything on Ubuntu 20.04

> sudo apt-get purge grub*
> sudo apt-get install grub-efi
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> sudo update-grub

Already tried the solution above.

> user@user-Nitro-AN515-54:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> 3 not fully installed or removed.
> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
> Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu44) ...
> dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
> installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
> No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi:
> grub-efi depends on grub-efi-amd64 (>= 2.04-1ubuntu26.11); however:
> Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package grub-efi (--configure):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
> grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
> Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
> Package grub-pc is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
> No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> grub-efi-amd64
> grub-efi
> grub-efi-amd6-signed
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first method

step 1:
you can try using `--force` so, try using `sudo apt-get --force-yes remove --purge grub*` or with dpkg `sudo dpkg -P grub*`

step 2:
after this you can use  `sudo dpkg -C` or `dpkg --list | grep -ve 'ii\|^rc'` (I would suggest trying both) and confirm that there is no `grub-efi-(anything after this)` package listed.

step 3:
if you confirm this then you can go with `sudo apt-get install grub-efi` and install it and then do `sudo update-grub`.else go with second method

Second method

step 1:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

now do step 2 and then step 3 of first method.

**IMPORTANT**
if you successfully remove grub-efi by any method then I would suggest do not turn off your computer before installing it again